# How do I embed external .wav files in my JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, external, embedded-resource

I want to have one JAR and nothing else, I want all external resources to be contained in it. How do I do that?

Comment: How are you building your jar ?

Comment: Meaning, are you using command line tool or using some build tool like Ant or Maven ?

Comment: i just press run button in the Eclipse IDE :DD

Comment: Go to command prompt and type  `jar -uvf <your jar name>  <your files/resources to be put in jar>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do with the media will make it into what is typically called an 'embedded resource'.  For that scenario, simply put the WAV files in the Jar and access them by URL.  See this [info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: how do i put something in a Jar?

Comment: A jar is just a zip file with another extension. Depending on the build system you are using you'll do one way or another. But the goal is having a jar with all your .class (code) and all your other files (resources as .wav and so on)

Comment: +1 @Andrew: `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` is also handy. I prefer it when I need an InputStream.

Comment: @helios so you're saying that I should put all my resources in `src` folder?

Comment: @Nika: well, if you're using Eclipse then yes, it will pack all resources alongside compiled classes. The `Export | Java | Jar` option has a checkbox that says *include generated classes and resources*. Resources means exactly that: non Java files that exists in your src folder.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze : Else you can do that manually, here is one example, [HOW TO MAKE .jar FILE MANUALLY](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9613766/1057230)