# Making jar files (jira plugin)

Tags: java, sdk, jar, jira

I'm making plugin for Jira and found new problem. When I'm making .jar file - my PC makes it in a wrong way. At the same time, PC of my co-worker makes everithing perfect from the same source. What can be the problem? JDK version or Atlassian SDK? Or something else?

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my_Plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>my_Plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2</version>

<organization>
    <name>Example company</name>
    <url>http://example.com</url>
</organization>

<name>SmartAct</name>
<description>This plugin for Atlassian JIRA.</description>
<packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.activeobjects</groupId>
        <artifactId>activeobjects-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.19.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                <log4jProperties>src/log4j.properties</log4jProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <jira.version>6.0.4</jira.version>
    <amps.version>4.2.3</amps.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>saucelabs</id>
        <url>http://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian maven1</id>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/maven1</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian old</id>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Can you give details as to how you are creating the jar, such as scripts or a pom file?

Comment: added pom.xml to topic

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Could not find the main class" error when running jar exported by Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612918/could-not-find-the-main-class-error-when-running-jar-exported-by-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

1. The shown pom.xml does not contain the closing  tag, copy and paste mistake?

   1. Never tried repository and pluginRepository inside my pom.xml, I always use the ~/.m2/settings.xml; are your url's reachable?
   2. Does atlas-mvn dependency:tree list all jars or are sume "gone missing"?
   3. Are you compiling manually or from within Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ...? Mind you, the IDEs usually com with an (incompatible) Maven(3) version that breaks while compiling atlassian plugins 95% of the time. To be absolutely sure, run manually from the shell.
   4. Your 'PC' might just have the wrong encoding. Usually Maven tells you while compiling what encoding it uses, UTF-8/ISO-8859-x/CP-1252/whatever and that this is platform dependant. Atlassian products (generally) require UTF-8 for everything. The message looks like this: [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
   5. Last, but not least, please try to build **only** for JIRA 6.0 **not** 6.0.4.

If possible, post the messages from you atlas-package command so we can try to guess what might be wrong. Please also specify your development environment, IDE/OS/Encoding of Shell, and your target platform, i.e. JIRA 6.0.4 under Windows x64or whatever.

Regards, Holger

@Paul: BTW: this has nothing todo with Running from inside Eclipse, you need a JIRA instance for those type of plugins, see here: [Atlassian JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)