# How can i make jar file in java?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am beginner in java. I want to make a jar file means when i double click on jar file it automatically open not via cmd. Following program run successfully though cmd but i want to run via double click please help me.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class JavaTree {

    JFrame jf;
    JTree jt;
    JScrollPane jp;

    public JavaTree(String s) {
        jf=new JFrame(s);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Style");

        DefaultMutableTreeNode color=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Color");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode font=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Font");
        root.add(color);
        root.add(font);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode red=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Red");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode blue=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Blue");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode green=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Green");
        color.add(red);
        color.add(blue);
        color.add(green);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode bold=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Bold");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode italic=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Italic");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode un=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("UnderLine");
        font.add(bold);
        font.add(italic);
        font.add(un);
        jt=new JTree(root);
        jp=new JScrollPane(jt);
        jf.add(jp);
        jf.setSize(400,500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String...d) {
        new JavaTree("Java Tree");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9613766/1057230), hope it helps :-)

Comment: Are u using some IDE? If u use NetBeans just clean and bulild, it will create a .jar file on dist directory.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: One more [related example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15187181/1057230) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do it thus:

Go to the directory that contains the `JavaTree.class` file

Run the following commands

```
jar -cvf JavaTree.jar *.class
jar -uvfe JavaTree.jar JavaTree
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, you have to just :

1- use the [jcreator](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html)

or

2- look at 
[this topic](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/243325-how-to-create-a-java-executable-jar-file/)