# Compressing an Extracted Jar File

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, executable-jar, meta-inf

I have extracted a jar file and made some change on it. Now, how can i compress again it as an executable jar file?

Thanks.(Sorry for my bad english.)

Comment: Hopefully this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9613766/1057230) be of some help on the topic :-)

Answer (score 7):

Try :

`jar cf jar-file input-file(s)`

according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: When I want to execute the resulting jar file I get the error: no main manifest attribute,

Answer (score 1):

By Using Eclipse IDE You can Create your jar file

Below i have one link from which you can learn how to make jar file executable

https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm

But For that You have to make project in Eclipse.

Comment: It's not a eclipse project. It's jrupy-complete.jar file and it contains different subfolders and meta-inf folder.

Comment: than you have to convert into project than make changes as per your requirenmnt and generate jar

Answer (score 0):

You can use this very simple library to **pack/unpack jar file** programmaticaly

[JarManager](https://bitbucket.org/ReaperSoon/maven-repo/src/367c0bcb2749/fr/stevecohen/jarmanager)

Very simple

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import fr.stevecohen.jarmanager.JarUnpacker;

class Test {
   JarUnpacker jarUnpacker = new JarUnpacker(); 
   File myfile = new File("./myfile.jar");
   File unpackDir = new File("./mydir");

   List<File> unpacked_files = jarUnpacker.unpack(myfile.getAbsolutePath(), unpackDir.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

You can also use **maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.stevecohen.jarmanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>JarManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Check the last version with the link bellow to use the last dependency

Please use my [public issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ReaperSoon/maven-repo/issues) if you find some bugs

Answer (score 0):

```
jar cvf filename.jar *
```

- To compress all extracted file to single jar file you can use *
- To add single file you also can use filename instead of *

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html