# Manifest file never saves what I set it to when making jar file

Tags: java, jar

Ive been trying to create a jar file for quite a bit of time now... Ill show my code

**Main Java File:**

```
Main.java
```

**MANIFEST.txt:**

```
Main-Class: Main
```

**Jar Creation Command:**

```
jar cmf MANIFEST.txt GUI.jar *.class
```

I compile and run the java files and I do not notice any issues until after I create the Jar file... After I create the Jar file, when I try and launch it (from the command line) it gives me the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

I took the jar file after trying to re-create the Jar several times with slightly different commands, and extracted the contents of the car. Afterwards I discovered that this is what actually loaded into the manifest.txt file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
```

Im not sure how, or why it happened.

#### I changed the Manifest.txt file to what the file originally was before the creation of the Jar file and recompressed the file into a jar and tried to run it again, but still nothing...

Comment: Please do clarify, are you actually pressing __ENTER__ key inside `manifest.txt` after writing `Main-Class: Main`? If you could paste `Main.java`, we'll try to create a `.jar` file for you :-), if that is not too much to ask for. Here for trying, a small [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15187181/1057230) and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9613766/1057230), hopefully it might can help

Comment: I can do that In just a moment... I got a bit fed up and am mostly done remaking the whole thing in NetBeans... I know its not a good idea to give up that quickly when you are learning but I just needed this to work haha.

Comment: The issue I had seemed to have been fixed after I reinstalled my JDK... What could the reasons be behind that fixing it?

Answer (score -1):

Obviously you are running

```
java jar ...
```

instead of

```
java -jar ...
```

Comment: That is actually what I was doing, I typed my example incorrectly. Sorry about that!

Comment: No. You left out the `-`. You were trying to run a main class called `jar`, as per the first example. The error message proves it.