# create kafka topic using vertx javascript code

Tags: apache-kafka, vert.x

Can any one provide me with a script to create Kafka topic with Vertx using JavaScript. If not can you explain how to do it in Java. How can I run it using [this](https://github.com/zanox/mod-kafka) code.

Comment: have you tried to follow the instruction given in their documentation ?

Comment: I dont know how to use maven

Comment: [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) would be a good start.

Comment: iam getting error main manfest not found while executing jar file

Comment: how you are executing it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612918/could-not-find-the-main-class-error-when-running-jar-exported-by-eclipse

Comment: I got a jar file in target folder mod-kafka-1.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar.Iam trying to run it using  java -jar mod-kafka-1.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar