# .jar files get error could not find main class

Tags: java, jar

I have been working on a .jar file and it was running on double click.

I installed the JRE 7 and it got errors. I uninstalled  the JRE 7 and changed the .jar files to open with `javaw.exe` now it get the error `could not find main class`.

I used Netbeans to create the .jar file please help I'm stuck here

Now I having JDK 6 with net beans 7.2 .

The program runs property from the command line.

Comment: You can take a look at this thread.

[Stack overflow thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428079/could-not-find-the-main-class-when-double-clicking-jar-file

Comment: Make sure that you've allowed for parameters to past to `javaw.exe`.  It reads `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*` on my Windows 7 box

Comment: Can u tell me how to set parameters to java.exe -jar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the manifest file inside the jar contains the main-class field and the corresponding class name by opening in archive.