# Main startup class could not be found

Tags: java, classnotfound

I have built an application using Swing and exported it as runnable jar file and converted it to .exe file. Its working fine in some systems, but in other systems a popup error is shown up saying "**The main startup class could not be found**" and the application exits.

Has anyone faced this kind of problem?

Comment: Did you try running the exported jar *before* converting it to an `.exe` file? That would at least tell us at *which step* the problem is. Also: have you set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable on your system?

Comment: I had this problem too. I had made my project with java8 but I switch to java7 during work. So, You try to create a new project and clean and build it again. Now, try to create .exe again.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your generated Manifest file for classpath.

Check this link...["Could not find the main class" when double-clicking .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428079/could-not-find-the-main-class-when-double-clicking-jar-file)

Comment: This is what my MANIFEST.MF file has `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .` ...and I included a line `Main-Class: mypackage.myclass` but still im getting the same error...any idea?

Comment: `Class-Path: .` means it will search for classes based on the local directory. That's a **bad idea**! The jar file itself should contain all required classes and resources! Also, please *update your question* when you add new information, don't just add it as a comment to random answers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile at the same level you specify in Jar2Exe.

In Eclipse, right click the project > properties > Java Compiler > JDK Compliance > 1.6 (for instance).

Then, specify 1.6 as the minimum required when you build the .exe file.